# What makes a call in Swift expensive?

Tags: swift, function, class, oop, methods

When discussing a method, function or computed property call, what does it mean when a call is considered expensive? Please advise

Answer (score 0):

An expensive method would be one that uses a lot of resources. Resources such as time and hardware.